# How to return a single row for rows that have duplicate values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I would like to do it quickly, not by going from row to row as it is a rather big file. I can't find anything on pandas, although pivot_table seems to be quite close... Here is what I have:

```
A    B
0    Tree
0    Leaves
0    Buds
1    Ocean
1    Blue
```

And what I want:

```
A    B
0    Tree ; Leaves ; Buds
1    Ocean ; Blue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you can join things by using `some_delimiter.join(things_you_want_to_join)`, e.g. `','.join("abc") == 'a,b,c'`.  We can apply that to the `B` column after grouping on `A`:

```
>>> df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(' ; '.join)
A
0    Tree ; Leaves ; Buds
1            Ocean ; Blue
Name: B, dtype: object
```

and then to get `B` back as a name:

```
>>> df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(' ; '.join).reset_index()
   A                     B
0  0  Tree ; Leaves ; Buds
1  1          Ocean ; Blue
```

Answer (score 2):

We can perform a groupby on 'A' and then apply a function (lambda in this case) where we join the desired delimiter `;` with a list comprehension of the B values.

If you want to restore the B column you can just call `reset_index()`:

```
In [238]:

gp = df.groupby('A')
gp.apply(lambda x: ' ; '.join([t for t in list(x['B'])])).reset_index()
Out[238]:
   A                     0
0  0  Tree ; Leaves ; Buds
1  1          Ocean ; Blue
```